# Visual display Debuggers like DDD

Tags: c, macos, debugging, ddd-debugger

I am having massive troubles installing ddd on my Mac OSX lion.

Anyone know of any other visual display debuggers like ddd ?

It has to Visual display debugger.

I have eclipse on my mac , does it come with a debugger? if yes how to get to it?

Comment: Eclipse comes with a built-in debugger with a good UI. The following  tutorial should help you get started.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/